# Is it necessary to escape underscores in \href with dollar signs or \?

Tags: math-mode, hyperref

The tutorial [LaTeX/Hyperlinks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks) shows that the following should be compilable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{mailto:a_b@c.def}{a_b@c.def}

\end{document}
```

However, I cannot compile it. Is it necessary to escape underscores in `\href`  with a pair of `$`s or `\`?

Note that escaping the underscores with a pair of `$` does not make sense in the above context, of course!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to escape the *printed* text (the second argument) since that is interpreted by LaTeX. The first argument is set according to the PDF specification which doesn't follow the same rules:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{mailto:a_b@c.def}{a\_b@c.def}

\end{document}
```

You could also use `\textunderscore` in place of `\_`.

Comment: Should this be edited in the Wikibook the OP linked to? Or could there be a case when the code as shown there would just work?

Comment: @Jake: It looks to me like a bad example, since `\nolinkurl` removes the requirement to escape the underscore. Perhaps if the example used `my-address@wikibooks.org` instead, it would be less error-prone.

Comment: I really miss an `\email` macro by `hyperref` which handles this itself.